# Recursively adding to dictionary in Python

Tags: python, recursion, dictionary, directory

I have a directory structure:

```
test
    test2 
        test3
```

and I am trying to make a dictionary of it that should look like thus:

```
{'name': 'test', 'sub': [{'name': 'test2', 'sub': [{'name': 'test3', 'sub': []}]}, ]}
```

To do this I use the following recursive function:

```
def dir_struct(rootdir):
    a = {}
    rootdir = rootdir.rstrip(os.sep)
    a["name"] = rootdir
    a["sub"] = []
    for path, dirs, files in os.walk(rootdir):
        for dir in dirs:
            b = dir_struct(dir)
            a["sub"].append(b)
    return a
```

But with it I get

```
{'name': 'test', 'sub': [{'name': 'test2', 'sub': []}, {'name': 'test3', 'sub': []}]}
```

Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that `os.walk` is already a recursive function, which goes through the whole directory structure.

One solution is to use `os.listdir` instead of `os.walk`.
This does what you want:

```
def dir_struct(rootdir):
    a = {}
    rootdir = rootdir.rstrip(os.sep)
    a["name"] = rootdir.split(os.sep)[-1]
    a["sub"] = []
    for dir in os.listdir(rootdir):
        b = dir_struct(rootdir + os.sep + dir)
        a["sub"].append(b)
    return a
```